# Cross domain, but server data not of JSON format

Tags: php, json, ajax, get, cross-domain

Hej, I want to access web service from a remote server and there is a cross domain problem. I tried JSON since it worked in another script but this time it generated "SyntaxError" and then I found the data on the service is not of JSON format.

So now I am thinking about two ways. Firstly, changing the format to be JSON; Secondly, I have read some article which suggested [PHP Web Proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html). But it seemed that both ways needs some codes on the service side, any method that just involving coding on the client side? And for the first way, how can I format the content to JSON?

Comment: -1 SO is not a replacement for [basic research](https://www.google.com/search?q=JSON+cross+domain).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @Sazzad Hossain Khan, thanks for help, so it's about coding on server side? is there any way to solve this by only programming on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are in need of a server to get services. There have two generic request and response formats: either XML or JSON format. So whenever you need a service, you will send a request to the server. If the server has the requested service available then the server will response you. I prefer JSONP for this.

So for Cross-domain communications with JSONP you can follow: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

And to response as JSON format you may need to return:

```
$myReturnData = array("its"=>"an array","its"=>"an array");
  print $_GET['jsoncallback']. '('.json_encode($myReturnData, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE).')';
```